# Letters tty terminal text mode are very small in debian. How to increase?

Tags: debian, tty

My Debian 7 is with letters tty terminal text mode are very small. How to increase?

I know that Fedora 20 is possible to install in a troubleshooting installation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup
```

Then choose your font + size :)

[Source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/173220/how-do-i-change-the-font-or-the-font-size-in-the-tty-console)

Comment: Ok polym, but is possible to change this when I install my debian??

Comment: that i don't know sorry. Maybe try to find that option while installing your debian system? Or just run above command after installation :).

Comment: I didn't find. I know that in fedora 20 is possible when you use a Troubleshooting Installation. But in Debian, I already don't know how to do this.